# Laravel with php 7: No supported encrypter found

Tags: laravel, encryption, composer-php

This question has been asked for many times, so let me list the steps I did on it:

1. Setting `'cipher' => 'AES-128-CBC',` (original AES-256-CBC);
2. `php artisan key:generate`
3. pasting the new key to the `.env` file

but the error remains the same.

In phpinfo, `mcrypt` shows enabled, although there's no extension in `httpd.conf`. Some answers says that the extension is integrated with php 7.

The project is downloaded from git and installed with `composer` and `npm`, the `.env` file was sent from another developer.

Answer (score 1):

Might be  there is a problem with your mcrypt. You need to check whether  mcrypt php extention is installed or not and it should be enabled.
on command prompt run `php -m | grep mcrypt`
if you couldn't find in your apache just install it. 
https://www.myoddweb.com/2010/11/18/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-windows/ here is the link.

Comment: The phpinfo shows that mcrypt is enabled, although I did not find php_mcrypt.dll extension in httpd.conf file. Some answers said mcrypt is integrated in the library of php 7, I'm not sure if I still need an extension file.

Answer (score 0):

After performed last two steps from you listed into your problem, have you clear config cache?.

If not then you must run `php artisan config:clear` because Laravel caches all config data.

Also why you change `cipher`? if no reason, revert it with original and performed the steps again.

Might this work for you.

Comment: I used the original env with the key first, but the error occurs either after I cleared the config cache or not.